# What are the best practices for storing user configuration?

Tags: internet-explorer, bho, ieaddon

What are the best practices to tore user configuration (which the user can change) in a browser extension for Internet Explorer?

on Chrome/Safari/Opera, I use localStorage. In Firefox, I use the PreferenceManager XPCOM.

I'm not sure what to use for IE:

- **registry**: seems to work fine for "small" values, Bu I doubt I could use fir for a list of 100+ URLs for example
- **local file**: in protected mode, the BHO can write to low integrity location, meaning Temporary folders, so it is likely the file will be wiped out at some point
- **remote file**: privacy issues, and resource issues

I could not find information from Microsoft on the subject.

Comment: localStorage has been in IE since version 8.

Comment: @DanRedux: do you have any link? Form what I've found, localStorage can be called from JavaScript to associate data with a domain. I don't see how this can be used in a BHO. Anyway, I'm looking for solutions that works with IE6 to IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully understand the documentation, but since IE5, there's been a "UserStore" that you can use to store information in IE only.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(v=vs.85).aspx

I think it's what you want, but MS has bad documentation.

Comment: Seems to be used on client side only (see also this question:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/8a78ef71-ce39-4c61-bb9f-f7d7c0a9f09b)

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? If you want server-side you have millions of options.. If you're making an extension you want to use local storage which means client-side.

Comment: I mean this is available from the HTML page only, not from the BHO